# C++ program freezes randomly for no apparent reason

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Can someboy explain to me why when I compile this code, sometimes it reaches the "might or mighnot" point, but most of the times it freezes on the "hi" and nothing happens. The program doest make another iteration either. I'm really puzzled; I'm using Code::blocks on Windows as IDE. And this only happens when I set a BigInteger for multiplication >= 100.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

    class BigInteger
    {
        vector<int> representation;
    private:
        vector<int> truncateZeros()
        {
            int end = 0;
            for(int i = this->representation.size()-1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                if(this->representation[i] != 0)
                {
                    end = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            vector<int> truncated;
            for(int i = 0; i <= end; ++i)
            {
                truncated.push_back(this->representation[i]);
            }
            return truncated;
        }
    public:
        BigInteger(int number)
        {
            this->representation.resize(100);
            int pos = 0;
            while(number != 0)
            {
                this->representation[pos] = number % 10;
                number /= 10;
                ++pos;
            }
        }
        BigInteger(string number)
        {
            this->representation.resize(100);
            int pos = 0;
            for(int i = number.size()-1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                this->representation[pos] = number[i] - '0';
                ++pos;
            }
        }
        BigInteger(vector<int> number)
        {
            this->representation.resize(100);
            int pos = 0;
            for(int i = number.size()-1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                this->representation[pos]=number[i];
                ++pos;
            }
        }
        vector<int> getInteger()
        {
            vector<int> copy;
            vector<int> truncated = this->truncateZeros();
            copy.resize(truncated.size());
            std::copy(truncated.begin(), truncated.end(), copy.begin());
            reverse(copy.begin(), copy.end());
            return copy;
        }
        string toString()
        {
            string result;
            vector<int> truncated = this->truncateZeros();
            for(int i = truncated.size()-1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                result.push_back(truncated[i] + '0');
            }
            return result;
        }
        BigInteger multiplyBy(BigInteger bigNumber)
        {
            vector<int> bigNum = bigNumber.getInteger();
            vector<int> sum(this->representation.size());
            int size = bigNum.size();
            for(int j = 0, i = size-1; i >= 0; --i, ++j)
            {
                int desetici = 0;
                vector<int> result(this->representation.size());
                int startAt = 0;
                for(int k = 1; k <= j; ++k)
                {
                    ++startAt;
                }
                for(int k = 0; k < this->representation.size(); ++k)
                {
                    int res = this->representation[k] * bigNum[i];
                    if(desetici > 0)
                    {
                        res += desetici;
                        desetici = 0;
                    }
                    if(res > 9)
                    {
                        result[k + j] = res % 10;
                        res /= 10;
                        desetici = res % 10;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result[k + j] = res;
                    }
                }
                //now sum
                for(int k = 0; k < result.size(); ++k)
                {
                    sum[k] += result[k];
                    int pos = k;
                    while(sum[pos] > 9)
                    {
                        ++sum[pos+1];
                        sum[pos] = sum[pos] % 10;
                        ++pos;
                    }
                }
                cout<<"hi"<<endl;
            }
            cout<<"Might or might not";
            //now we return sum
            reverse(sum.begin(), sum.end());
            return BigInteger(sum);

        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        int a = 10000;
        BigInteger big = BigInteger(a);
        vector<int> rep = big.getInteger();
        for(int i = 0; i < rep.size(); ++i)
        {
            cout<<rep[i];
        }
        cout<<endl;
        string asResult = big.toString();
        cout<<asResult<<endl;
        cout<<"Try to multiply:"<<endl;
        BigInteger res = big.multiplyBy(BigInteger(876));
        string aaa = res.toString();
        cout<<aaa;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: any reason you can't use the debugger?

Comment: It doesn't give me any useful info, or atleast which I can understand.

Comment: It's likely just taking a lot of time to do calculations. Also, I get warnings about signed and unsigned comparisons. You might want to look into those. Anyway, mine stops finishing instantly somewhere between 500 and 600.

Comment: No useful information? If you step through it, you'll find where it gets stuck..

Comment: @user1113314 It seems you're writing out of bounds. Indeed, if I remove all the code in the loops, valgrind doesn't complain. Check your logic.

Comment: `result[k + j]` goes out of bounds when `k` reaches its max and `j>0`.

Comment: Funnily enough, it finishes instantly at 512 and seems to be stuck in an infinite loop that, judging by the time it takes to close, allocates a lot of memory, at 513.

Comment: @Matt Indeed, that is the culprit. Post that as an answer, as the unsigned/signed compares aren't causing the crash (IMO). I narrowed it down by selectively deleting code until valgrind stopped complaining.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now i just set the max of k to be k < this->representation.size()-j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result[k + j]` goes out of bounds when `j>0`.